# How to make the dropdown button default text remain the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown button with an opening and closing arrow. The default text of the button is "closed" and when being clicked the button should be opened, it should change its content(from "closed" to "open") and arrow. All these things happen when I click on the button but when I once click on the button and its text changes to "opened" then if I click on an empty space in my page it starts to change my button text as if the default text was "opened".How to make the default text of my button always remain "closed" if I click on the empty space in a page after clicking on the button once?

here is my code

```
<div class="btn-group main_button_group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle main_btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
Closed
<span class="arrow_close"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.main_btn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 55px 10px 24px;
    top:31px;
    right:-20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    border:0 none;
}
.main_btn .arrow_close {
    background-image: url("../arrow_close.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right:25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.main_btn .arrow_open {
    background-image: url("../arrow_open.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right:25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("main_button_group button").click(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span').hasClass("arrow_close")) {
            $(this).find('span').addClass("arrow_open").removeClass("arrow_close");
        } else {
            $(this).find('span').addClass("arrow_close").removeClass("arrow_open");
        }

        var myspan = $(this).find('span');
        $(this).text(function (i, text) {
            return text === "Opened" ? "Closed" : "Opened";
        });
        $(this).append(myspan);
    });
});
```

Comment: make a fiddle, I suggest to change background images to colours for the fiddle to prevent 404 errors

Comment: Copy&paste your code in fiddle gives very strange visual results. Are you using bootstrap? Adding it cleans it up.

Comment: Yes it is bootstrap. I'll make a fiddle